# Change part of the value in a HashMap using java

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` with `String` as the key type and `String[]` as value type. 
I want to be able to change part of the value (a `String` array).

I am storing files' contents using this HashMap by saving the file name as the key and its contents as the value (`String[]`).

I've succeeded in collecting all the data for this HashMap. I want the value
to be displayed in this way:

```
Key: alert
Value: 

    0-=Rule_Name,Configuration_Set_ID,Alert_UID,Headline,Create_DateTime
    1-f5_high_compression_profile,,211,61b6cc42-0b32-4bd9-a3be-a98d7144ca85,Compression profile gzip level too high,1565003688537
    2-f5_automap_enabled,407,0b380e7d-22f9-40c2-8277-3a5ed2ea7116,Automap enabled,1565003696956
```

I want to replace value of `epochtime` in the string to `Date` with this convention `yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss` for each record (epoch time may be different in the file).

```
public void createHashMapWithAlertCSVContent() throws Exception {
    for(String item: lstServer) {
        String[] contentCSVStr=
            CmdHelper.Remote.File.cat(SERVER,INDENI_INSIGHT_PATH + 
            "/"+item).split("\n");
        mapServer.put(FileUtil.removeExtension(item), contentCSVStr);
    }
    if(mapServer.containsKey("job")) {
        mapServer.remove("job");
        Assert.assertEquals(mapServer.size()-1, lstServer.size());
    } else {
        Assert.assertEquals(mapServer.size(), lstServer.size());
    }

    mapServer.entrySet().forEach(entry-> {
         System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + 
         entry.getValue());
    });
}
```

What I expected to happen was any entry of epoch time in the array of string would be replaced to `yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss` convention.
I have this string `f5_high_compression_profile,,211,61b6cc42-0b32-4bd9-a3be-a98d7144ca85,Compression profile gzip level too high,1565003688537`.
I want to change `1565003688537` to look like the `yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss` convention.

`1565003688537` may not be the same value when I read the content of the CSV, so it has to be able to handle that.

I want to change each entry of ecpoh time into date format value.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you want to store the format `yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss` in file, change the logic that writes to file.

If you just want to read it in `yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss` format, change the reader logic which reads the line. Read the epoch and replace it with formatted date.

Comment: @npinti - I'VE EDITED MY QUESTION - please notice the question a t the bottom of the question

Comment: what do you mean by `'1565003688537' may not be the same value when I read the content of the CSV so I have to make it generic` ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I mean that when I run the program the epoch time on the csv file may be different epoch time and I want to be able to locate epoch time and change it to date convention mentioned above.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I mean taking this epoch time and convert it to yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss format. But I want to change any entry in the array of string which is the value of the hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can just read the value by map.get(key) then edit it and the put it again with map.put(key, value).

If the value is of a muatable type, eg. String[] then you can just make modifications directly on this object, because the map is referencig to this object and not holding a copy.
eg.

```
String[] value = map.get(key);
value[0] = "new String";
```

If you want to change the size of the String[] then you need to create new list and put it under same key to replace the previous value, or you can change the type to use List instaed of String[] so it will be easier to modify it.